# How to fix randomly populating HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm getting the lat/lng of a location based on excel sheet input & outputting onto an HTML table. I'm able to get the correct coordinates; however, they do not output to the right column (they randomly populate the table, I want them next to their corresponding address). I discovered that the coordinates will populate correctly when I have the alert(newArray[n]); before the geocode searches.
Is there anyway I could fix this? Below is a snippet of my code:

```
var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById(tableID).tBodies[0];
for (var i = 0; i < tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) {
  for (var k = 1; k < rowLength; k++) {
    var oCells = oTable.rows.item(k).cells;
    var cellLength = oCells.length;
    newArray[n] = '';

    for (var j = 2; j < cellLength; j++) {
      var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
      //tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
      tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
      var value = cellVal + ' ';
      newArray[n] = newArray[n] + value;
    }
    //alert(newArray[n]);
    MQ.geocode().search(newArray[n])
      .on('success', function(e) {
        var results = e.result,
          result,
          latlng,
          best;

        result = results.best;
        latlng = result.latlng;

        var x = document.getElementById("grid1").rows[o].cells;
        x[cellLength].innerHTML = latlng.lat;
        var y = document.getElementById("grid1").rows[o].cells;
        y[cellLength + 1].innerHTML = latlng.lng;
        //alert(latlng);
        o++;
        n++;
      });
    i++;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: There's an extra `}` at the end of the code.

Comment: Where do you define the variable `o`?

Comment: You're calling an asynchronous function `MQ.geocode().search()`. They don't necessarily complete in the same order that they're called.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it in the snippet. I put var o = 1;

Comment: The problem is that the order that the different callbacks will be called is random so you can't rely on loop indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a trick to populate tables asynchronously... but it requires a different approach to inserting cells like what you're doing.

Build your full table beforehand in a string with a dummy image in each cell like this...

```
<td>  <img style="display:none;" src="X" onerror="this.outerHTML=FetchSomeValue(this.row,this.col);">  </td>
```

And display the string to screen. As each image load FAILS, it'll call the function **FetchSomeValue(Row,Col)** and populate correctly by replacing the dummy image.

NB: I use this technique with images or iframes (depending) all the time, flawlessly.
Images and Iframes have a ONLOAD event which we can take advantage of.